# Subviews are not removing while removing the superview in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, addsubview

I created a UIView.A search bar is added as subview on the view.The search bar is also created through code.

I have given a UIAnimation to the view to get a dropdown like effect to the view.

Upto this point it is working fine.

The problem is when i remove the superview the view is go but the search bar is still there.

**Here are some codes:**

```
@interface ATViewController : UIViewController<UISearchBarDelegate>
{
    UIView *dropView;

    UISearchBar *searchBar;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    dropView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 70, 150, 100)];
    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,150,0)];
        [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender{
   // self.searchBar.delegate = self;
    [dropView addSubview:searchBar];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.9];

    dropView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    dropView.frame = CGRectMake(70, 70, 150, 550);
    self.searchBar.frame=CGRectMake(0,0, 150, 40);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [self.view addSubview:dropView];
}
-(void)doSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    switch (sender.numberOfTapsRequired) {
        case 1:
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

            dropView.frame = CGRectMake(70, 70, 150, 0);
            self.searchBar.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 0);
            [UIView commitAnimations];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

**Adding the subview**

[image: Adding the Subview]

**After removing the subView**

[image: After removing the view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not removing the super view in code. You are just reducing its height to zero. If you want the `searchBar` to be clipped along with the `dropView` then set `dropView`'s clipToBounds to YES.
i.e;

```
dropView.clipToBounds = YES:
```

before you reduce its height to zero.

Noticed that you are reducing the search bars height to zero as well. But I think you are not allowed to edit the height of the UISearchBar.